# Rails AutoComplete, not working on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, elasticsearch, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Okay, so I installed this gem:
https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete

And configured it and it works really well, I even used the CSS from one their examples on my web app for autocompletion and it works locally.

Problem was after I pushed to github, I tried pushing to heroku and heroku kept aborting rake assets compilation because of invalid punc. My application.js file is really small and I don't see any errors :/

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require highlight.pack
//= require turbolinks


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
  });

  $('.search-query').bind('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data {
  $('.search-me').trigger('click')
  });
});

jQuery(function($) {
$("tr[data-link]").click(function() {
window.location = this.dataset.link
});
```

I do have other coffeescript files but those are all empty execept for one listings.coffee

```
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

But I don't think this is causing a problem either.

I've been trying for a week to get autocomplete to work, so I've tried adding multiple libraries and css files to go with them, could that possibly be the problem?

EDIT: If anyone needs to know the site, it's rpastie.xyz ( it's just like a pastebin ) and here's my github repo for it: https://github.com/ilovemysillybanana/pastie I just noticed my repo says it's 72% javascript now because of that library I added, it's huge.

EDIT:
The error I get when I checked the javascript developer console is this:

```
application.self-1a1712b70bebadf78204351833a15e6960033fd69d5422f3985a59622371194‌​2.js:30 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I assume this means there's an issue on line 30, I've checked but it looks fine to me I don't really understand it.

http://pastebin.com/T1bXxMcy I put it on pastebin, but only a small part of it(only first 50 or so lines, most are comments or white space).

I'm using the free tier of Heroku, if anyone is wondering. I definitely want to undo the last commit I did but I really don't wanna mess things up worse it added all the assets to git and heroku and now the project is huge.

Comment: Do you see any errors when you open the developer's console in your browser? Does it work locally?

Comment: I just checked the developers console and I found an error, but I don't understand it o.o; 

    application.self-1a1712b70bebadf78204351833a15e6960033fd69d5422f3985a596223711942.js:30 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Also, it does work locally it works great locally that's why I'm so confused.

Comment: i think assets compile issue and your auto complete lib is not included in server side press ctrl+u and see the source of the page

Comment: but the autocomplete lib is a ruby gem, it's not a javascript

Comment: It is javascript, even though it's a ruby gem most of it is implemented in JS which is why you need to add that line to your `application.js`. It seems as though you may have a JS error that's preventing autocomplete from running properly.